# HSQL Query constraint for alphabets and numbers

Tags: sql, hsqldb, check-constraints

How I have a column Firstname which should be only Alphabets 
and phone number which should be only numbers in HSQL

i wrote something like

```
ALTER TABLE USER 
ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK_USER_FIRST_NAME CHECK (FIRST_NAME  NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z ]%' )
```

But it allows `Tp1` which i don't want. 
Can someone help me with constraint in HSQL

Comment: It should works [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/391797). Try quoting identifier `CREATE TABLE "User" ...` and `ALTER TABLE "User"...`. Share also info about default COLATION

Comment: @lad2025: no, it doesn't work. The SQL LIKE operator doesn't support "ranges" or regular expressions (SQL Server's T-SQL deviates from that - but doesn't support _real_ regular expressions)

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` doesn't support regular expressions. The only wildcards it supports are `%` for multiple characters and `_` for a single character. To match against a regular expression you need [`regexp_matches()`](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#N1382C)

```
ALTER TABLE user 
   ADD CONSTRAINT check_user_first_name 
   CHECK (regexp_matches(first_name, '[A-Z]+'))
```

This will allow only uppercase letters, so you probably want to use `'[A-Za-z]+'` instead.  It also requires at least one character in the name. If you want to allow empty strings, change the `+` to `*`. This will still allow null values though.

---

Note that `USER` is a reserved keyword in SQL. You shouldn't create a table with that name. If you try this e.g. on Oracle or PostgreSQL it will fail. The name requires to be quoted - which is not a good idea. You should find a different name.